# simpleschema validation and before insert collection hook

Tags: meteor

When using a before.insert collection hook like this:

```
collection.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
});
```

if createdAt  is a mandatory field (declared with SimpleSchema), then as validation occurs before the insert hook, the server is firing a "Error: createdAt is required" exception.

How validate the schema *after* the insert hook has occured ?

Comment: I'm not sure unfortunately, but considering validation is usually for user input this is likely irrelevant. Simply remove createdAt from the schema definition as your hook will guarantee correct data anyway.

Comment: SimpleSchema validation is not only for user input. You could have a mandatory field (as "userId"), but not at the moment of user input, only at document insertion (a user is not required to input its own ID when filling a form, the server side is taking care of adding the userId). I agree that the hook will guarantee correct data anyway, I'm just not happy with this :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Collection2 to your project (`meteor add aldeed:collection2` assuming it isn't already added), and make use of `autoValue`. AutoValue operations are run on the client only for validation, but the actual value saved will always be generated on the server, regardless of whether the insert/update is initiated from the client or from the server. [From the docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2).

```
createdAt: {
 type: Date,
  autoValue: function() {
    if (this.isInsert) {
      return new Date;
    } else if (this.isUpsert) {
      return {$setOnInsert: new Date};
    } else {
      this.unset();
    }
  }
}
```

Your other option would be to set the field as optional, and use your hook, but that's not ideal.

Comment: I didn't know about autovalue. But that's against what I would like to do. The before.insert collection hook is inside a package I'm writing that take care of automatic field insertions (https://atmospherejs.com/mickaelfm/vermongo). I can not do the insertion in the schema definition.